# Script to stop Youtube video from playing in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have slider with a video and some pictures . When I try to move to the next picture the video keeps playing . I researched on stack and tried some of their Ideas but its not working in my case.

SO I tried to create a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/UvL7N/1/) of it here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/UvL7N/1/) .  To slide to next image you just have to click on the left or right side of the video .

The `script` for slider is as follow

```
$("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    startidx: 0,
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 540,
    namespace: "transparent-btns"
});

//$('.transparent-btns_nav').trigger('click');
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav', function (event) {
 //here I guess we can add some script to stop the video 
});
```

And the `HTML` you can see in the fiddle .

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really easy fix. On your youtube video src, you will see an autoplay attribute:

```
autoplay=1
```

Set this to

```
autoplay=0
```

This will stop youtube from auto playing the video.

Here is your updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/UvL7N/8/

Comment: I saw you changed the autoplay=1 to 0 but In the fiddle its still not working